# filtered chain complex definition

Tags: homological-algebra, filtered-modules

Define a filtered chain complex to be a chain complex $\{C_{\bullet}, d\} $with a filtration $F_{\bullet}C_{\bullet}$. (assume an increasing filtration)

My question is: are all the objects in the filtration groups? i.e. must $F_{-1}C_{n}={0}$? can $F_{-1}C_{n}= \emptyset$ ?

Comment: Yes, they must be groups. Why do you want to allow the empty set?

Comment: They are groups and even sub-chain-complexes. I don't think it is required that a filtration is bounded below in general.

Comment: I was thinking empty sets because a finite filtration is defined as $\emptyset \subset F_1K \subset F_2K \subset ... F_nK$. I would like to take a filtered simplicial complex and induce a filtered chain complex. I think you can do this by first constructing a chain complex $(K^n)$ indexed by dimension n then converting this into a filtered chain complex by $F_pK^n= C_n(F_pK) $= all n chains in $F_pK$.

Comment: When you construct the free vector space on the empty set you get the zero vector space.